# WPDB Update with multiple conditions

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have tried to update data with `wpdb->update`. I am trying to update data WHERE product_title => $title & WHERE course_id is empty. I can add the product_title but how can I course_id empty conditions.

```
    global $wpdb;
    $voucher_codes = str_replace(' ', '', $voucher_code);

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'xyz';
    $update_data = $wpdb->update(
        array('course_id' => $id,  ), 
        array('product_title' => $title) //where
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;
    $voucher_codes = str_replace(' ', '', $voucher_code);

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'xyz';
    $update_data = $wpdb->update(
        array('course_id' => $id,  ), 
        array(
           'product_title' => $title,
           'course_id' => ''
        ) //where
    );
```

Comment: Your answer would be a little more meaningful to others if you shared some explanation of what was wrong in the first place.

Comment: You can get details from here. 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/
$wpdb->update( $table_name, $data, $where );